# How did gravity affect gas clump after the big bang

Tags: gravity, big-bang

In the first episode of Cosmos. It was said that after the big bang, gravity worked to pull clumps of gas together and heating them.

My question is what was exerting the gravitational pull to make these clumps of gas come together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is what was exerting the gravitational pull to make these clumps of gas come together?

[Here is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) the history of the universe in pictorial form. It includes the observations and theoretical deductions up to now:

[image: history of universe]

Exactly your question, about "climping" was asked about galaxies and clusters of galaxies , which have a uniform distribution wherever we look and the same is true for the [cosmic microwave background.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background). At the very  early times  of 10^-32 seconds,  thermodynamics for the whole universe could not be invoked  to explain clustering and uniformity of clusters, because  due to the [light cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) relativity did not allow communication over the whole universe.

This forced to consider quantization of gravity which by its nature would create clumps in primordial energy way before any gasses were formed. This means that when the universe reached 1microsecond , where protons were formed , the masses available were already in large clumps. At about three minutes when the first elements were formed there were clumps of gas composed of these elements. These  balls converged slowly to their center of mass by the usual gravitaitional force because as time goes on Neutonian mechanics is sufficient to explain the development, creating the galaxy clusters and the galaxies we see now.

Answer (score 0):

It forced the gas to be more concentrated in gravitationally strong regions of space. This is why you hear of a clumpy universe in the beginning of the Big Bang.